# outer measure of sum is greater than or equal to outer measure of union

Tags: measure-theory

How do I show this? I am having a hard time grasping this.
I have read that this is the 1-dimensional case of Brunn-Minkowski Inequality but I have no idea how to prove this:

m(A + B) $\geq$ m(A $\cup$ B)

where A and B are disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

I'm thinking I could use sub additivity and/or the fact that m(x+A) = m(A), x $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ but I do not know how to to start.

m(A) is the outer measure of A: inf{$\sum$I: I is an open interval and A $\subseteq \cup I$}

Comment: I don't think there is a simple direct proof like the one you are trying. BTW, even if A and B are not be disjoint you get $m(A+B) \geq m(A)+m(B)$. I suggest you read a proof of Brunn -Minkowski inequality. Ref. https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0ahUKEwi7-7i7pNfZAhUSSo8KHQKND2cQFghKMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffaculty.wwu.edu%2Fgardner%2Fgorizia12.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1JVlTU3AbWWxeHU570EFlc

Comment: I checked the reference you gave but I don't really see the connection of the inequality to the inequality of Brunn-Minkowski. Is it possible to prove this by definition or just by properties of outer measure?

Comment: You cannot easily handle the measure of the algebraic sum A+B by basic measure theory arguments because you don't get the sum from a countable number of unions intersections and complements.